# MySQL Workbench Database Migration - data truncates after apostrophe

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, data-migration

I'm using MySQL Workbench Data Migration Wizard to migrate an MS SQL Server R2 database to MySQL database. The schema and data are migrating properly but for the fields having apostrophe, the data after apostrophe is truncated.
Here is an example:

Original data in a field(in SQL Server):

```
<p>It has come to the Association’s attention that some crew members are being required to perform administrative/office duties whilst on airport reserve.</p>
<p>As members would all be aware, your Enterprise Agreement states that Airport Reserve is duty time spent by a flight attendant at the airport awaiting assignment to a flight or duty (Clause 10.1)</p>
<p>However, in the past it has been agreed between the Association and the Company that checking and loading of an aircraft would be an appropriate requirement and should a flight attendant offer to assist the Company in performing other duties within their capabilities, that is also acceptable, but cannot be required.  The Association’s position on this particular issue has been long standing and, in a time where administrative positions have been reduced and with a staff freeze in place, we can see no reason to reconsider this.</p>
```

Returned data (in MySQL):

```
<p>It has come to the Association
```

As you can see, everything after the apostrophe is missing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the migration tool interprets the data as incomplete quoted string and discards hence that part. Better file a [bug report in MySQL bug system](http://bugs.mysql.com) to get this fixed.